# How can I check if the player is holding their arms out in UnityVr?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

Im trying to add a glide mechanic to my vr game. But to activate this mechanic, I want the players to have to hold their arms out. How would I check if they were holding their arms out?

Comment: check hand-distance from body?

Comment: Yes, im trying to figure out, basically, if they are t-posing

Comment: Check the distance between controllers. If it's over a threshold, and not too far below the head, they're probably trying to fly. You could even include a "calibration" step if you find simple thresholds are unreliable. Have a user stand in a somewhat comfortable flying position, and store the relevant parameters for your flight activation.

Comment: @Bart Thank you.. but the issue that I'm having is that I don't know how to find the distance between the controllers. This is the most complex thing I've done on Unity so far. (I have XR implementation)

Comment: If you know how to get the positions of the two controllers (transform.position for example), you can calculate the distance between them with `Vector3.Distance(a,b)`. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html

Comment: @Bart Thank you so much for your input on this, I just have a few more questions. I don't know how to get controller position, do you know how to do this?